# How to calculate total price in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the price of the product from db using the product id i have stored in php array.

i have a php function where in i want to hold a total of all the products purchased. here i am getting the cart items and i am calling the function which should hold total amount. i am passing the value `price` each time when i retrieve the product from cart.

for example for first item iteration i send value 300, and for second 400, for third 900.

i want to add up all these and get total price of 1600 in `payableAmount()`
how can i do this?

```
function getCartitems($product_id){
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT product_id,product_name,product_price,product_image_url FROM product_list WHERE product_id='$product_id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);      
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {              
        echo "<tr><td><img class='cart-image img-responsive' src='".$row["product_image_url"]."'></td><td>".$row["product_name"]."</td><td><b>&#8377; </b>".floor($row["product_price"])."</td><td><a href='mycart.php?action=remove&product_id=".$row['product_id']."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> remove</a></td></tr>";
        $price = $row['product_price'];
        payableAmount($price);      
        }
    } else {
        echo "There are no such items";
    }   
    $conn->close();
}

function payableAmount($totalPrice){    
   // calculate total price here
    $total = $totalPrice;
    echo $total;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to have a function to calculate something which can be calculated within while?

Comment: `$price = $price + $row['product_price']`.... if you want the total price.... put it inside a loop.

Comment: Why you are not using while loop to calculate sum

Comment: You can do it inside your SQL statement using sum(price)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just simply update your query instead like as

```
$total_price = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {              
  echo "<tr><td><img class='cart-image img-responsive' src='".$row["product_image_url"]."'></td><td>".$row["product_name"]."</td><td><b>&#8377; </b>".floor($row["product_price"])."</td><td><a href='mycart.php?action=remove&product_id=".$row['product_id']."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> remove</a></td></tr>";
  $total_price += $row['product_price'];
}
```

Comment: But will it work for the given product_id in loop? Because the query will get the different product_id each time. and all the price has to be calculated.

Comment: Then it won't work then you need to simply need the summation of the prices. I'll update it

Comment: I tried it but i am not getting total. instead i am getting price of each ex: item 1 => 35000 , item 2 = > 16000  Total should be 51000, but i am getting 3500016000

Comment: What's the value that you were getting within `$row['product_price']`

Comment: 3500016000 is the value i am getting within $row['product_price'];

Comment: Its working fine at my end are you using `.` operator instead of `+`

Answer (score 2):

Just declare total outside -

```
 $total =0;
function payableAmount($totalPrice){    
   // calculate total price here
   global $total;
    $total += $totalPrice;
    echo $total;
}
```

Comment: in PHP? :) Won't work my friend unless you use globals or any other more clever solution

Answer (score 1):

Create a Variable outside the function. Then you add the price to this variable in the funtion. and use

```
$total += $totalprice.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the while loop to calculate the price. Declare a variable `$totalPrice` and then sum it within the while loop.

```
function getCartitems($product_id){
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT product_id,product_name,product_price,product_image_url FROM product_list WHERE product_id='$product_id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);      
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $totalPrice = 0;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {              
        echo "<tr><td><img class='cart-image img-responsive' src='".$row["product_image_url"]."'></td><td>".$row["product_name"]."</td><td><b>&#8377; </b>".floor($row["product_price"])."</td><td><a href='mycart.php?action=remove&product_id=".$row['product_id']."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> remove</a></td></tr>";
        $price = $row['product_price'];
        $totalPrice += $price;      
        }
    } else {
        echo "There are no such items";
    }   
    $conn->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need simple modification in your payableAmount() function

```
function payableAmount(&$totalPrice){    
  // calculate total price here
   $totalPrice += $totalPrice;
}
```

Variable is passed now via reference so it will be modified after you do it you can echo $totalPrice and it will be changed, the other 2 options is to use static variable or global. However if I were you I wouldn't use function for such a simply task. Just declare `$total` before loop and inside loop `$total += $price;` and it is enough

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add the price in loop and get the same by storing it in variable.

payableAmount($price);//Not Need to call different function as it return only the current price,instead of this you can add the price as given below
$total_price+=$price;

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $totalPrice = 0; // Initialice the var before to go into the while loop
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {              
            echo "<tr>
                <td><img class='cart-image img-responsive' src='".$row["product_image_url"]."'></td>
                <td>".$row["product_name"]."</td><td><b>&#8377; </b>".floor($row["product_price"])."</td>
                <td><a href='mycart.php?action=remove&product_id=".$row['product_id']."'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> remove</a></td>
                </tr>";
            // increment the price...
            $totalPrice += $row['product_price'];
        }
        // Now you can use the $totalPrice var
    } else {
        echo "There are no such items";
    }
```

Comment: this will generate a warning: undefined totalprice

Comment: Ok, try to initialize the var before to go into the while loop :-)